# Ajax call nested php files

Tags: php, ajax

I am doing a `ajax` `POST` request to a `php` file. Lets call it `A.php`

This `A.php` file would then call `B.php`.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../../page_components/A.php",
            data: { // my data
            },
            success: function(response) {
                location.reload();
            },
```

**Problem Facing**: The success function is not called when A.php calls B also. It works fine if A.php doesn't call B.php

On my `A.php`

```
/* some stuff that a.php does
*/
include ('B.php'); // call B.php to handle other stuff
```

`B.php`

```
<?php

require '../../../../PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php';
require '../../../../PHPMailer/class.smtp.php';

// set relevant agency email to send to. $agency comes from A.php
switch ($agency) {
    case "1": $receiverEmail = "xxx@hotmail.com";
    break;
    case "2" : $receiverEmail = "zzz@gmail.com";
    break;
}


$mail = new PHPMailer();

// All the mail setting and stuff is here...
if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo 'Message was not sent.';
  echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
?>
```

Comment: The problem probably lies in B.php stopping A.php from returning the correct response, but it's difficult to say without seeing that code.

Comment: so your `A.php` and `b.php` output (or echo) nothing at all?

Comment: They both do echo something. I have tried and all function were running fine on both `php` files.  Just that the success function doesn't get called. `B.php` is just a PHPMailer to send email by getting the receiver_email and messagebody to be sent from A.php.

Comment: check console for any errors/output of echo statements.

Comment: depends on what ajax expects to get returned. try always to define the `dataType` in your ajax-call. in your case it would be `dataType: "text"`.

Comment: Alright somehow all is fine now. I guess there was some delay in sending the email earlier on which lead to no response on my `B.php`

Answer (score -1):

```
url: "../../page_components/A.php"
```

is that url supposed to be sending on B.php?
if it is then isnt the url supposed to be like this

```
url: "../../page_components/B.php"
```

Comment: Call `A.php` first on the ajax call. `B.php` is called by `A.php`